# Librería en python para topónimos

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Existe alguna librería en python que permita reconocer topónimos?

He visto que existe la opción

```
from geotext import GeoText
places = GeoText("London is a great city")
places.cities
```

Pero necesito no sólo poder reconocer si una palabra es nombre de ciudad, si no también de país o pueblo.

Comment: Para países tienes el atributo `places.countries`, el problema creo que va a ser lo de poblaciones pequeñas. Aunque se supone que usa http://www.geonames.org/ he probado con algunas localidades y no son detectadas.

Comment: Vale, aunque usa datos de geonames, lo hace de forma estática desde un archivo de texto, lógicamente limitado (15000 localidades). ¿Piensas acotar las búsquedas a un determinado país o a unos pocos? Lo digo porque sería trivial adaptar la librería para que haga uso de alguno de los listados de http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/, considerablemente más exhaustivos.

Comment: No pensaba acotarlo a ninguno ya que el objetivo es que reconozca cualquier topónimo, he estado haciendo varias pruebas y sobre textos reconoce términos como "opportunity" o "alliance" que son incorrectos.